# Carriage return in a bash variable

Tags: bash, carriage-return

I have a bash variable that ends with `\r\n`:

```
$ # Not the real command to get VAR's value, just an example
$ VAR="$(echo -en 'hello\r\n')"
$ hexdump -C <<< "$VAR"
00000000  68 65 6c 6c 6f 0d 0a                              |hello..|
00000007
```

I would like to drop the `\r` (the `\n` itself is correctly handled by bash).

I may trim it (`VAR="$(tr -d '\r' <<< "$VAR")"`), but that implies to run a process just for that task.

I tried using "Remove matching suffix pattern" bash feature, but cannot find which pattern to use (e.g., `${VAR%\r}`, `${VAR%\x0d}`, `${VAR%[\r]}`—but neither of them does work).

Any idea how to drop the `\r` without creating a subprocess?

Comment: `the \n itself is correctly handled by bash` Hope you know, that `$(...)` _removes_ the newline, and variable does not have a newline, and then `<<<` _adds_ the newline to the input of `hexdump`.

Comment: I did know that bash handles newlines, I did not know _how_.  Thank you for that info.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the ANSI C quotes. With substitution, use

```
var=${var//$'\r'}
```

If you want to only remove the `\r` before the final `\n`, you can use

```
var=${var%$'\r\n'}$'\n'
```

i.e. you have to remove both the `\r` and `\n`, so you need to add the `\n` back.

Comment: Indeed, bash itself handles the final `\n`, so `${VAR%$'\r'}` does work.  Cf. also KamilCuk's comment.

Comment: @audeoudh: If you "have a variable that ends with `\r\n`", then you need to handle it yourself. If bash already removed the `\n`, you can just `var=${var%$'\r'}`.